# Bootstrap 4 fieldset legend field at top and bottom

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Can anyone suggest how to add legend text on bottom border in bootstrap 4

I tried with `position` and `margin` But no use.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<fieldset class="border p-2">
   <legend  class="w-auto">Head</legend>
</fieldset>
```

expected view is

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no official way to achieve this yet, but using little css it can be achieved...

try this..

```
<fieldset style="padding-bottom: 1rem;">
<legend>Personal:</legend>
Name: <input type="text" size="30"><br><br>
Email: <input type="text" size="30"><br><br>
Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10">
<label style="position: absolute; margin-top: 1.8rem; margin-left: -11.6rem;background-color: white;">Hello:</label>
```

Make sure there is at least one field above that Hello Label or else it will be hidden...i hope it helps

adjust the margin-left according to your requirement....

[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYZjc.png)